# Making Another Screen in Xcode (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I'm developing my first app using the latest version of Xcode and the iOS SDK. I'm seeing a number of options, and quick Googling has failed me so far. I have one main screen set up for my app so far (it features a search text field which displays content in another text field), and I'd like to now make a second screen. I can do this in a number of ways, like have a switch where the text field changes to a picker control and such an action changes the behaviour, OR I can just switch to another view entirely. I figure learning the second method will be more beneficial to me in the future, so I'm wondering what I should make to do that. A View? Another storyboard?

Comment: Your problem is "quick goggling". You should read Apple's docs, particularly the ones on view controllers, and storyboards. You need to learn the way Apple has designed things before you start writing apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a view ; a view is equivalent to a page.
Storyboard is a collection of views/pages ; it helps keep views together, & then you can also organize your flows between views/pages 'within' the storyboard easily. Storyboard is like a Java/C++ package, whereas View is like a Class.

Comment: How do I define code for a second view? Xcode does most of the setup for me on my first view, so I imagine I define a new .m file to interact with this new view? Or do I do it from the original ViewController.m class?

Comment: Are you using storyboarding? The first step is dragging a new UIViewController to your storyboard. You then set the storyboard identifier of the view controller in the identity inspector. Once you've done that, you can present the new view controller from your orginal one using:    
`[self presentModalViewController:[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"] animated:YES];`

Comment: With this, I ended up with the following line of code (adhering to the fact that presentModalViewController has been deprecated in iOS 6): `[self presentViewController:[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"statView"] animated:YES completion:nil];` Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another UIViewController subclass and the XIB, and then #import it and then open it.

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```